# Creating a panel in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm moving a plugin from Firefox to Chrome. In Firefox its possible to create a separate panel attached to the current window instead of the popup you get in chrome.

I know Chrome allows you to insert scripts into a page. How would I add a panel to the bottom of the window using script insertion in a way that doesn't alter the layout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome API doesn't provide any help with this. You would need to insert and position the panel div manually through content script.

How to do style it:

- Set `position:fixed;bottom:0;` for the panel
- Set `margin-bottom` of the page body equal to panel height
- Look for absolutely positioned elements on the page that have `bottom` value set and decrease it by panel height.

Comment: That seems to create a div that floats over the contents. Is there anyway to move the page contents up to make space for the panel?

Comment: @usertest You do this by setting bottom margin on the whole `<body>`.

Comment: This may be of use if you are thinking about selectively showing the panel:  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1827-Using-jQuery-s-SlideUp-and-SlideDown-Methods-With-Bottom-Positioned-Elements.htm