# Build an UI for chrome extension to display the result from background script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

following is my manifest.json file

```
{
    "name": "Demo Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },


    "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-1.7.2.js","code.js"]
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.js","content.js"],
            "css": ["panel.css"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],

    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
    ]
}
```

My main extension logic is in the code.js file and even the results are available over there.
Now i have to dsiplay those results in a table to the users.
What will you suggest me to do.

I have no clue what to do.
Just i know that i have to build a UI and display my table on to it.

Thanking you all in advance  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dedicated page for you UI, for example, give it a name `ui.html`. Then you can open it when you need it as follows:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:chrome.extension.getURL("ui.html")});
```

In the page you can create an arbitrary UI, and fill it with appropriate data, which you may request from your background page directly (assuming the method `youMethodHere` is defined there):

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().youMethodHere();
```

This `ui.html` page will be displayed in a separate tab. You also have an option to create a popup page (presenting the same UI) which can be open by a user by clicking a browser action button. Just add to your manifest:

```
"browser_action":
{
  "default_title":"some title",
  "default_icon":"some_icon.png",
  "popup":"ui.html"
}
```

Comment: I know that thing.........But i want to create a panel like what is in firebug lite at the bottom.

How do I load my HTML UI on the current tab as a panel?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible in Chrome (at least at the moment). You may find more details and a kind of workaround in other questions: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199184/creating-a-panel-in-google-chrome) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102997/chrome-extension-how-to-dock-extensions-html-page-to-current-web-page).

Comment: But then how did firebug lite did it for chrome? They have designed their panel using HTML and CSS and they are loading it over the chome's interface. It appears like how you have ur extension's XUL Overlay over the browser's overlay.xul in firefox.

Comment: Did you read other people's answers I linked? They are very close to what FireBug Lite does. Did you try to install FireBug and investigate it with Chrome's developers tools? - In fact, this is just a div placed in the bottom of the page. This is not Chrome's native solution, so I suppose it can be buggy in some cases and interfere with a page where it's embedded.

Comment: Ya thats what.......

Beacuse of that i was avoiding it.
It is not safer to append something to the dom of the document.
Rather i wanted to append it to the dom of the current tab or the window.
But it seems it is not possible to do like that.
Trying with some other way now.